# decompile my own app ipa extracted from iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, simulator, ipa

I have lost an iPhone/iPad app due to a hard disk failure and I am trying to recover my code. I have found that I still have the app in the simulator, so I have been able to recover all the resources from the ipa's simulator file (as they are not encrypted). That is great. But the code is compiled (I think its an Intel binary file) so ... is it completely impossible to extract something readable from this kind of file?

Please note:
I am not talking about decrypt/decompile an ipa file from the Apple store or somewhere else. It's from the simulator.

I think it's impossible, but who knows!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1601

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that's not possible. Your source code is gone. You can find some recovery software that tries to restore deleted files. If you have used any source control management like CVS, SVN, Mercurial or GIT that would have saved you. Anyway Lesson learnt from this donot rely on your local harddisk for backup.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to salvage the overall structure of your code by using [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) on the executable binary.

It will not recover all the code, but should be able to recover all the class definitions. That is, if you have not stripped your binary from debug symbols.

Regarding the harddisk being unrecoverable I guess it all depends on how much money you are willing to spend on it. There are companies that specialize in recovering data from crashed disks, and to my best of knowledge they are able to recover practically any type of disk failure. The question is whether you are ready to pay that price, or if it would be cheaper to just reimplement the code.

Answer (score 3):

Change the .ipa suffix to .zip... uncompress. Inside you'll find the Payload folder containing an app. Open that app package and there are your files.

Works on a Mac. Not sure about Windows.

Comment: It does, but sadly it doesn't decompile the actual binary executable inside of the `ipa` bundle. I think that's what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score -3):

It is only way,if u can recover your hard disk.

you can not get data from .Ipa file.

Comment: Well, actually I could extract all the resources from the ipa file, because those are not encrypted in the simulator, but not the code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jorge could you explaine how you did that?

Comment: I'm sorry! I don't remember. It was three years ago :) But I remember that it wasn't hard. I think that it was just finding the ipa file and extranting it as if it was a zip. But maybe the simulator has changed since then or it wasn't that way. Sorry again for my bad memory.

Comment: downvoted; you can get at least resources and classes/funcs structure